# Problema de indexacion con prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema.

agrego articulos por medio de importacion de .csv y los agrega de manera satisfactoria, los puedo ver directamente en la pagina y todo esta bien.

pero me doy cuenta de que al hacer busquedas estas no me encuentran ningun articulo.

buscando un poco me doy cuenta que en la configuracion de busqueda me sale que tengo 0/0 productos indexados, y ya problemas las 2 opcioens de agregar los productos que faltan al indice y reconstruir el indice completo.

[image: Esto es lo que me aparece]
alguien me puede ayudar a hacer que mis productos me salgan todos completos ?

[image: Adjunto imagen donde muestro los productos que tengo agregados]

utilizo prestashop 8.0.4

hasta el momento solo he intentado acuatlizar el archivo searche.php pero no ha funcionado para nada `your text`